# Azure Contributor Role is deprecated as of 2022, what replaces it for App Services?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I am doing a course in Azure / Git.  Assigning a Contributor role to an app registration for an App Service is required.  The contributor role was not showing up, Google to the Rescue? (Nope ...)

Google got me to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/mem/configmgr/app-management/contributor-role-not-assigned-for-web-app).

I'll need the correct permissions / access to continue.

Looking on Google for what replaces this, I'm not able to find a fast path.

If anyone has faced a similar situation upgrading a web app or creating a new one, that would be helpful.

What role or roles should now be assigned to effect contributor level access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first click into the "Add role assignment" page for Access Control, with the default settings, the "contributor" role does not show up:

[image]

But if you select the "Privileged administrator roles" tab it does show up:

[image]

You can then add the "contributor" role to a user, group, service principal, or identity.

Comment: My man :).  Thanks very much for this help.  Sorry if I went off the hook earlier, perhaps Dai didn't see what I wanted, perhaps it could be stated better.  This really helps.

Comment: You're welcome!  When they first made this change a few months ago it got me too and I was scrambling around trying to figure out where the Reader role went to.  Using a role with less permission than Contributor is best, but sometimes in a non-production environment you just want to test something and get it to work without looking up the exact role you need.